# How to align text under itself in straight line without starting from under the icon?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
      <td> 
          <span className="support-matrix-page-check-icon" />
          <span className="support-matrix-page-p-small"> I want this text to be on next line but not start from right under icon </span>
</td>
```

So my problem is next line 'but not start from right under icon' should be aligned under 'I' character not under the check icon. How can I align it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Two ideas:

1. Put both `span` inside a container with `position: flex`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  
  /* Just for the demo */
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
```

2. Put both `span` inside a container with `position: relative`, add `position: absolute` to the icon, and add `padding-left` to the container to push the text to the right.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;

  /* Just for the demo */
  width: 200px;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm.. you deserve 50 points :)